# Is there a way to detect if a primitive argument is variable size?

Tags: c++

We use an in house serialization library. It uses a templated function to write variables to a stream.

One thing you have to be careful about when using it is to ensure that you use specific length types. You're fine with int32_t etc, but if you pass an 'int', you might find it being unpacked on a system where int has a different size. Then the unpacking fails.

Is there a way of causing a compiler error if somebody tries to use a non fixed size variable?

Comment: Provide specializations that throw an error for all the non fixed size types.

Comment: P.S. If you're writing binary values don't forget about endianness.

Comment: @MarkRansom int32_t is defined in Visual Studio as "typedef int                int32_t;". The code won't compile if I create overloads for 'int' and 'int32_t'.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Sorry to waste your time. Even tested it: http://ideone.com/1qqxpa

Comment: How does your serialization work such that the deserializer could get the wrong type back?

Comment: `int32_t` **is** `int` on many platforms. Honestly, sounds like either the library or your serialization format... sucks (sorry :))

Comment: You should be storing information about the type, so if someone uses `int` and it happens to be a 32-bit signed number, store that it's a 32-bit signed number, **not** that it's just "int". Then when unpacking you use whatever type that is on that system, whether it be `int` or `long` or whatever.

Comment: If you're using systems without 32-bit `int` there's no guarantee that the system even defines `int32_t`, it's an optional typedef.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way of causing a compiler error if somebody tries to use a
>   non fixed size variable?

No. This is completely nonsensical since `int32_t` might well be defined as a typedef to `int` (and very often is). I.e. `std::is_same<int, std::int32_t>::value == true`. You cannot distinguish them.

Serialize the size of `int` and check for it on the platform you're deserializing on. That is, check that `sizeof int` has the same value as on the platform that serialized the data.

Comment: Yes, define the binary protocol, and then check on (de-)serializing that the code fits.